# Comare the list of Maps with their values in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have two lists which contain list of maps in it.

```
List<Map<String,String>> list1=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>()
List<Map<String,String>> list2=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>()

        def m1 = [name: 'abcd', value:'1.2.3']
        def m2 = [name: 'xyx', value:'4.6.3']
        list1.add(m1)
        list1.add(m2)

        def m3 = [name: 'abcd', value:'1.2.6']
        def m4 = [name: 'xyx', value:'4.6.9']

        list2.add(m3)
        list2.add(m4)
```

I need to compare the values of each map and display if the values are mismatched

the output should be something like this:

the Value of the "abcd" from the list1 is Lesser than the value from the list2

**Note:The names in the two lists are same but values may vary**

Please let me know if we have any built in functions in the groovy,I am new to the groovy programming

Comment: why you creating two lists `list1` and `list2` but adding all maps into `list1`?

Comment: sorry its a typo mistake,edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//i think better to have just a map for this task for faster access
//you can convert your list of maps to map: list1.collectEntries{[it.name,it.value]}
def map1 = [:]
map1['abcd'] = '1.2.3'
map1['xyx'] = '4.6.3'

def map2 = [:]
map2['abcd'] = '1.2.6'
map2['xyx'] = '4.6.3'

map1.each{k1,v1->
    def v2 = map2[k1]
    if(v1!=v2) println "the value of $k1 in list1 `$v1` is "+( v1>v2 ? "greater" : "less" ) +" then `$v2` in list2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,It is working for only one value.I have verified with the below code def m1 = [name: 'abcd', value:'1.2.3']
        def m2 = [name: 'xyx', value:'4.6.3']
        list1.add(m1)
        list1.add(m2)

        def m3 = [name: 'abcd', value:'1.2.6']
        def m4 = [name: 'xyx', value:'4.6.9']

        list2.add(m3)
        list2.add(m4)
        Map  map1 = list1.collectEntries()
        println("map one:"+map1)
        Map  map2 = list2.collectEntries()
        println("map two:"+map2)

Comment: use this commant to transform list to map: `Map map1 = list1.collectEntries{[it.name,it.value]}`